# Reading a github file using python returns HTML tags

Tags: python

I am trying to read a text file saved in GitHub using requests package.

Here is the python code I am using:

```
import requests
url = 'https://github.com/...../filename'
page = requests.get(url)
print (page.text)
```

Instead of getting the text, I am getting HTML tags.

How can I read the text from the file instead of HTML tags?

Comment: Make sure you're getting what you think - what do you get if you put that URL into your browser? Github generally returns a page with the file embedded - you may need to adjust your URL to point directly to the file. Try `https://github.com/repo/raw/.../filename`, which redirects to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/repo/.../filename`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I put the URL into the browser and I am getting the file. Anyway I have tried https://github.com/repo/raw/.../filename link also, I am able to open up the file in raw format over browser, but again while reading through python, I got HTML tags only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some good solutions already, but if you use `requests` just follow Github's [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents).

The endpoint for all content is

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
```

But keep in mind that the default behavior of Github's API is to encode the content using `base64`.

In your case you would do the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import base64
import requests


url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{repo_name}/contents/{path_to_file}'
req = requests.get(url)
if req.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    req = req.json()  # the response is a JSON
    # req is now a dict with keys: name, encoding, url, size ...
    # and content. But it is encoded with base64.
    content = base64.decodestring(req['content'])
else:
    print('Content was not found.')
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but I end up with an error saying: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: I can not replicate your error, even if I get a 404 response (the result in that case is `keyError`). Tried it with Python 2.7 and 3.4. Can you give me the URL you used or the user, repo and the path? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I think I constructed the URL wrong that's why I got the previous error. Now I got the URL right, but I am getting 404 response. Do you know how to avoid this? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Hi. I thought so. There are some ways you can do this. Like check the response code or check the dictionary for 'message'. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I said, I have created the URL as per your response, but still I couldn't read the contents. I still receive the error code 404. I think URL still need some more info. to read the contents, may be authentication details or access tokens I am not sure about. Can you help me here.

Comment: You can add the access token to the header like this `requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'token {your token}'})`, example: requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'token c7abb397c7abb397c7abb397'}). Everything else stays the same. You get the token under your Github Settings -> Personal Access Tokens. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: The file in which I am using the above piece of code is used by others also, does my token works for all? because everybody has their own authorization details right? If it works, it is secure to use token generated by my authorization details? Thanks for your responses.

Comment: *Short version*: the token works for others, but I'd advise against your proposal. *Long version*: The token is bound to your profile. Whoever uses your token interacts with github through your account. When you generate the token you do have the option to limit it's [scope](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) (the things you can do with it), but there is no way to limit the token to read-only. If you chose this option, make sure to limit the scope to repos. However, my advice would be to include some option for others to use their access tokens. I hope that is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Info. really helpful. Though still I need to find a way to limit the token.

Comment: `content = base64.b64decode(req['content'])` works better.

Answer (score 8):

You can access a text version by changing the beginning of your link to

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/
```

Answer (score 4):

Thank you @dasdachs for your answer. However I was getting an error when executing the following line:

```
content = base64.decodestring(req['content'])
```

The error I got was:

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/base64.py in _input_type_check(s)
    511     except TypeError as err:
    512         msg = "expected bytes-like object, not %s" % s.__class__.__name__
--> 513         raise TypeError(msg) from err
    514     if m.format not in ('c', 'b', 'B'):
    515         msg = ("expected single byte elements, not %r from %s" %

TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str
```

Hence I replaced it with the below snippet:

```
content = base64.b64decode(json['content'])
```

Sharing my working snippet below (executing in Python 3):

```
import requests
import base64
import json


def constructURL(user = "404",repo_name= "404",path_to_file= "404",url= "404"):
  url = url.replace("{user}",user)
  url = url.replace("{repo_name}",repo_name)
  url = url.replace("{path_to_file}",path_to_file)
  return url

user = '<provide value>'
repo_name = '<provide value>'
path_to_file = '<provide value>'
json_url ='https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{repo_name}/contents/{path_to_file}'

json_url = constructURL(user,repo_name,path_to_file,json_url) #forms the correct URL
response = requests.get(json_url) #get data from json file located at specified URL 

if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    jsonResponse = response.json()  # the response is a JSON
    #the JSON is encoded in base 64, hence decode it
    content = base64.b64decode(jsonResponse['content'])
    #convert the byte stream to string
    jsonString = content.decode('utf-8')
    finalJson = json.loads(jsonString)
else:
    print('Content was not found.')

for key, value in finalJson.items():
    print("The key and value are ({}) = ({})".format(key, value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Patrick's answer, I'm going to show you my code for how to do that.

```
import requests
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...'
page = requests.get(url)
print page.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first clone the repo, either via bash, or using a python library like [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Then just open and read the file locally.